# openocd fails to load board/ti_cc26x0_launchpad.cfg

Tags: openocd, jtag

Has anyone got openocd to work with the TI cc2640r2 launchpad? I built the latest openocd source but it fails to initialise.

OS is Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and openocd was built with

```
configure --enable-xds110 --enable-cmsis-dap
make
make install
```

Running

```
openocd -f board/ti_cc26x0_launchpad.cfg
```

gets the output

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev-00676-g346ce2f1 (2019-02-05-00:53)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
adapter speed: 2500 kHz
Error: The 'jtag configure' command must be used after 'init'.
```

placing 'debug level 3' statements inside the script files show that it is failing within target/ti_cc26x0.cfg at line 25, which is

```
jtag configure $_CHIPNAME.cpu -event tap-enable "icepick_c_tapenable $_CHIPNAME.jrc 0"
```

The scripts must have worked (at least once) as they are part of the source distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I use the zephyr folk of open-ocd:

```
git clone https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/openocd.git
cd open-ocd
configure
make
make install
```

I also needed to reduce the JTAG clock speed:

```
diff --git a/tcl/board/ti_cc26x0_launchpad.cfg b/tcl/board/ti_cc26x0_launchpad.cfg
index 3613a47f7..2580faa52 100644
--- a/tcl/board/ti_cc26x0_launchpad.cfg
+++ b/tcl/board/ti_cc26x0_launchpad.cfg
@@ -2,6 +2,6 @@
 # TI CC26x0 LaunchPad Evaluation Kit
 #
 source [find interface/xds110.cfg]
-adapter_khz 2500
+adapter_khz 1500
 transport select jtag
 source [find target/ti_cc26x0.cfg]
```